# Regular expression not containing 101

Tags: regex

I [came across](http://www.public.asu.edu/~ccolbou/src/355hw2s12sol.pdf) the regular expression not containing 101 as follows:

> 0<sup>∗</sup>1<sup>∗</sup>0<sup>∗</sup>+(1+00+000)<sup>∗</sup>+(0<sup>+</sup>1<sup>+</sup>0<sup>+</sup>)<sup>∗</sup>

I was unable to understand how the author come up with this regex. So I just thought of string which did not contain 101:

> 01000100

I seems that above string will not be matched by above regex. But I was unsure. So tried translating to equivalent pcre regex [on regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/r/fA2oY1/1), but failed there too (as it can be seen my regex does not even matches string containing single 1.

Whats wrong with my translation? Is above regex indeed correct? If not what will be the correct regex?

Comment: Question: would it not be easier to have a regex that matches strings *containing* 101 and then keep only the unmatched strings ?

Comment: That string is [matched](https://www.regex101.com/r/fA2oY1/2). Do you need to match a string that does not contain 101?

Comment: It doesn't look very clear what the meaning of `+` is in your question. To me, it seems as if a `+` in the same line as the numbers is intended to mean what's typically expressed as `|`. That's not how you translated it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the explanation in the right side tab in regex101 it tells you what your regex does( I think you misunderstood what list operator does) , inside a list operator ( `[` ) , the other characters such as `(` won't be metacharacters anymore so the expression `[(0*1*0*)[1(00)(000)]` will be equivalent to `[01()*[]` which means it matches `0 or 1 or ( or ) or [`

The correct translation of the regular expression `0∗1∗0∗+(1+00+000)∗+(0+1+0+)∗`

 will be as follows:

```
^((?:0*1*0*)|(?:1|00|000)*|(?:0+1+0+)*)$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zL6cB3/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://debuggex.com/r/ot1fnY3Ce-jv3APn)

What your regex `[(0*1*0*)[1(00)(000)]*(0+1+0+)*]` does:

`[(0*1*0*)[1(00)(000)]*    ->    matches any of characters 0,(,),*,[ zero or more times followed by`

`(0+1+0+)*   -->  matches the pattern 0+1+0+ 0 or more times followed by`
`]  --> matches the character ]`

so you expression is equivalent to

`[([)01](0+1+0+)*]` which is not a regular expression to match strings that do not contain `101`

Comment: Yes  thanks I didn't know inside `[]`, meta characters are not allowed. I was thinking `[]` is like "any character out of", so just put multiple character sequences inside `()` to make "any word out of ". Poor me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bit shorter expression `^0*(1|00+)*0*$`

https://www.regex101.com/r/gG3wP5/1

Explanation:

- `(1|00+)*` we can mix zeroes and ones as long as zeroes occur in groups
- `^0*...0*$` we can have as many zeroes as we want in prefix/suffix

---

Direct translation of the original regexp would be like

```
^(0*1*0*|(1|00|000)*|(0+1+0+)*)$
```

**Update**
This seems like artificially complicated version of the above regexp:

- `(1|00|000)*` is the same as `(1|00+)*`

  - it is almost the solution, but it does not match strings `0`, `01..`, and `..10`
- `0*1*0*` doesn't match strings with `101` inside, but matches `0` and some of `01..`, and `..10`

  - we still need to match those of `01..`, and `..10` which have `0` & `1` mixed inside, e.g. `01001..` or `..10010`
- `(0+1+0+)*` matches some of the remaining cases but there are still some valid strings unmatched

  - e.g. `10010` is the shortest string that is not matched by all of the cases.

So, this solution is overly complicated and not complete.

Comment: I think this one should be the standard solution for this home work assignment and not the original regex  which is pretty complicated for back engineering. I guess the author of the original regex lacked the insight, that "we can mix zeroes and ones as long as zeroes occur in groups"

Comment: @ead , I wasn't trying to simplify regex or anything, I was trying to show where the OP went wrong by not knowing the change of metacharacters in the regex quantifiers :), If this was a question about `regex that do not match strings with 101` , the answer would have been different :)

Comment: yeah your regex is far more intuitive than the one given in slides. Just wondering if you can explain the logic behind slide's regex too...?

Comment: You can reduce the steps needed, if you write your pattern like this: `^0*(?:1*0{2,})*1*0*$`

Answer (score 1):

**0* 1* ( (00+000)* 1*)* (ε+0)**

i think this expression covers all cases because --
any number apart from 1 can be broken into constituent 2's and 3's i.e. any number n=2*i+3*j. So there can be any number of 0's between 2 consecutive 1's apart from one 0.Hence, 101 cannot be obtained.

ε+0 for expressions ending in one 0.

Answer (score 0):

The RE  for language not containing 101 as sub-string can also be written as `(0*1*00)*.0*.1*.0*`

This may me a smaller one then what you are using. Try to make use of this.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression I got (0+10)*1*.  (looks simple :P)

I just considered all cases to make this.

you consider two 1's we have to end up with continuous 1's
case 1:         11111111111111...
case 2: 0000000011111111111111...(once we take two 1's we cant accept 0's so one and only chance is to continue with 1's)

if you consider only one 1 which was followed by 0 So, no issue and after one 1 we can have any number of 0's.
case 3: 00000000 10100100010000100000100000 1111111111

=>(0*+10*)*1*
final answer (0+10)*1*.

Thanks for your patience.